# Granting access token type authorization_code getting error invalid_client

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

Im using django-oauth2-provider to build a authorization server. When i try to get access_token by using this command:

```
curl -d "client_id=513204402d4b4f4d62e2&grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=code" http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2/access_token
```

i get an error: invalid_client

I have been created my client with client_type is Confidential 
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your client is confidential, you must authenticate to issue an access token.

I suppose that it is a password client. You just have to add the `client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_HERE` parameter in your POST request or set your client credentials in the authorization header.

Example:

```
curl -d "client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&...
```

or

```
curl --user CLIENT_ID_HERE:CLIENT_SECRET_HERE -d "...
```

The authorization code grant type is a two step flow.

1. You get an authorization code just after the resource owner allowed your client.
2. You get an access token using the authorization code.

You are trying to send a `POST` request so I suppose that if you already have an authorization code.
You get an `invalid_request` because you do not set the `code` parameter in your curl command:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=CLIENT_ID_HERE&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE_HERE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI_HERE" http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth2/access_token
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but when i add client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET i get another error invalid_request. Do you have any idea?